# interrupts in c language

Tags: c

The following code uses the __interrupt as the interrupt service routine. How to comment 
on the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14
__interrupt double compute_area(double radius)
{
    double area=PI*radius*radius;
    printf("\narea=%f",area);
    return area;
}
```

This is the piece of code i got for solving. I haven't tried a program that uses interrupts before, but 
have read that the interrupts are not a function call and interrupt flags are used to set 
the interrupt service routine. I don't really have an in-depth knowledge of interrupts. How do you use them? Why would you use them?

Comment: And why would you be running a function like this as an interrupt...?

Comment: @bdonlan:I dont know how should a interrupt function should look like.But i got this program to solve.Read through about interrupts and came to know that it cant be called as normal function call.

Comment: How does one "solve a program" exactly?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here.  The `__interrupt` specifier you are using is not a part of the C language, but is instead an extension to the language. You will need to tell us what system you are compiling for in order to get a more specific answer for your use case.

That code does not appear to be a valid interrupt function.  Typically the arguments to the function will be `void` or the state of the registers when the interrupt occurred.  You can also typically change the value of the registers via the arguments (not always safe to do!).  Returning a value from an interrupt handler doesn't make a lot of sense either as it would not be called directly by user code.

Interrupts may be handled in many ways, but a simple mechanism would be to declare a function as an interrupt handler, a pointer to the function would be stored somewhere, and when an interrupt occurs on a specific CPU the registers functions would be called asynchronously (as the interrupt probably did not occur on your current thread).

I don't know that any of this generalist information will help you.  I can't really make out what you are asking here.  Perhaps if you narrowed things down a bit more we could offer more assistance.

Comment: To expand on your comment "Typically the arguments to the function will be void or the state of the registers when the interrupt occurred.", https://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPRUI04/the---interrupt-keyword-stdz0559860.html explains "You can only use the __interrupt keyword with a function that is defined to return void and that has no parameters.".